# Word 2010 proofing tools are automatically changing misspelled words

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, proofing

Word 2010 proofing tools are changing misspelled words how they want. For example I wanted to write the word *Like*, but I typed *Leke* and Word 2010 changed this to *Lake* without any warning.

Is there any option to just underline misspelled words so I can correct them how I want?

I am talking about proofing tools for non-English language.

Comment: [disable auto correction](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/turn-on-or-off-autocorrect-options-HP005189430.aspx)

Comment: yes, but that will disable all corrections

Comment: @shark4Ever just to be clear, it will disable the computer correcting things for you... it will not disable the computer from showing you where YOU need to make a correction.  If you want the computer to read your mind to know that you meant Like instead of Lake, when you typed Leke... that's something else entirely.

Comment: @Shark4Ever You have confused disabling auto correction with disabling the dictionary altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can [edit or remove](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/change-the-name-or-contents-of-an-autocorrect-entry-HP005208969.aspx?CTT=1) individual AutoCorrect entries.

If you want to just underline misspelled words and not use AutoCorrect, you can [disable](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/turn-on-or-off-autocorrect-options-HP005189430.aspx) it as Sb Sangpi said in a comment earlier.